# Clasificación Aleatoria SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, random

Estoy teniendo problemas para crear grupos de control en una segmentación, es decir, tengo una serie de id y estoy creando una columna donde me clasifique de manera aleatoria con 0 y 1 y para ello estoy utilizando:

```
Select *, case when a.clas = '1' then 'GC' else 'Send' end Clas_fin
from tabla1 t
left join (Select TOP (24795)                                             
       Id, (abs (checksum(newid())) % 1 + 1) as Clas
           from tabla1) a on t.id = a.id*
```

La manera en la que lo estoy haciendo es complicada por si sabíais alguna manera más fácil de hacerlo y que pueda coger un % de los id que necesito, por ejemplo, el 5% del total de la BBDD clasificármelos de manera aleatoria con 1 y 0.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar directamente el operador **Top**, para recuperar un **porcentaje** de los registros.

```
Select top(5) PERCENT
    *, case when RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))> 0.5  
            then 'GC' 
            else 'Send' 
       end Clas_fin
from tabla1 t;
```

[Top](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Además al usar top, siempre puedes aplicar un order by con un criterio. Aunque este también puede ser aleatorio.

Comment: Muchas gracias Javi, me funcionó correctamente, el problema es que para base tan grande como es mi caso (más de 2M de registros) veo que me está tardando demasiado, supongo que será por todos los join que tengo detrás que me están provocando esta demora.

Comment: 2 millones no es una tabla demasiado grande. Es probable que tengas problemas de diseño o índices. Es imposible saberlo sin tener mejor conocimiento de tu base de datos.

Comment: Era un problema de diseño sí, ya lo tengo solucionado. Muchas gracias!